# auto selected Item at first load

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, selecteditem, didselectrowatindexpath

I am using horizontal collectinview to display items. when user select/deselect the item I am adding/removing white border under the text.

here is the code

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)  {

        if cell.isSelected {

            bottomLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (cell.frame.height) - 7, width: (cell.frame.width), height: 3)
            bottomLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
            cell.layer.addSublayer(bottomLayer)
        }
    }
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) != nil {

            bottomLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    }
}
```

What I want is when I Load collection view first item should load with the `bottomLayer`(with underline)

I tried the code

```
let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
CollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])


collectionView(CollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPathForFirstRow)
```

but not working. I searched many questions but mostly all have same solution and its not working in my case. Can anyone help me here please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading `CollectionView` on button action, then

```
CollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
CollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
collectionView(CollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPathForFirstRow)
```

Call it in `viewDidAppear` :

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let indexPathForFirstRow = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
    CollectionView.selectItem(at: indexPathForFirstRow, animated: true, scrollPosition: [])
    collectionView(CollectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPathForFirstRow)
}
```

Comment: I am loading collectionview on button action event. So I added this code right after collectionview loads. And it fires didSelectItem method but it's failing at 'if let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)' Any suggestions ??

Comment: `CollectionView.layoutIfNeeded()` did the magic !! Thank you very much.